# Filtering Join in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle, join

**Problem:**
Each `KEY` in Table A should have **one RF record and one SJ record** however I have some duplicated SJ records.

**Objective:**
I wish to use the SJ records in Table B to identify which SJ record in Table A to keep.

**Info:**
Table A and Table B share a KEY and SEQ_NBR field.

**Inputs:**
Table A looks as follows

```
KEY    ID_TYPE   SEQ_NBR   BUS_NAME
1234      RF        1       COMP_A
1234      SJ        2       COMP_B
1234      SJ        4       COMP_C
5678      RF        1       COMP_L
5678      SJ        2       COMP_M
5678      SJ        3       COMP_N
```

Table B looks as follows

```
KEY    SEQ_NBR   BUS_NAME
1234      2       COMP_B
5678      3       COMP_N
```

**Desired Outcome:**
My output would look as follows

```
KEY    ID_TYPE   SEQ_NBR   BUS_NAME
1234      RF        1       COMP_A
1234      SJ        2       COMP_B
5678      RF        1       COMP_L
5678      SJ        3       COMP_N
```

Comment: Please, describe the logic behind this result in general words. There're a lot of ways to produce *this* result from *this* sample, but I hope you want to learn how to solve some *type* of problems, not a blackbox code that transforms A to B in unknown way.

Comment: What if you have duplicates that have no match in `b`?  Or multiple matches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
select key, id_type, seq_nbr, bus_name
from   (
         select a.*,
                row_number() over (partition by a.key, a.id_type
                                   order by b.key) as rn
         from   a left outer join b on a.key = b.key and a.seq_nbr = b.seq_nbr
       )
where  rn = 1
;
```

The left outer join adds columns from table `b` to those of table `a`. We need that for a single purpose: as we partition by `key` and `id_type`, we have partitions of either a single row or (two or more) rows. In the latter case, only one row has a non-null value in `b.key`. If we order by `b.key`, the row with non-null `b.key` will get row number = 1 (and we don't care about the rest).

Then the outer query simply keeps all the rows with row number = 1 and ignores the rest.

An alternative solution, using the `union all` of the two tables (slightly modified as needed) and basic aggregation using the `last` aggregate function:

```
select key, id_type, 
       min(seq_nbr)  keep (dense_rank last order by source) as seq_nbr,
       min(bus_name) keep (dense_rank last order by source) as bus_name
from   (
         select 'A' as source, a.* from a
         union all
         select 'B', key, 'SJ', seq_nbr, bus_name from b
       )
group  by key, id_type
;
```

You can test both to see which is more efficient on your data (if performance is important).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can count the number of duplicates.  Then use `left join` and filter based on both the count and the match:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             count(*) over (partition by key, id_type) as cnt
      from a
     ) a left join
     b
     on b.key = a.key and
        b.seq_nbr = a.seq_nbr and
        b.bus_name = a.bus_name
where cnt = 1 or b.key is not null;
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. Tables A and B only share 'KEY' and 'SEQ_NBR' but the first where clause you have a reference to id_type, is this intentional? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here goes your code:

```
select * from tablea a 
where   exists 
  (select 1 from tableb b where b.key=a.key and b.seq_nbr=a.seq_nbr)
or not exists (select tablea.id_type from tablea inner join tableb  on tablea.key=tableb.key and tablea.SEQ_NBR=tableb.SEQ_NBR and tablea.id_type=a.id_type)
```